# Accept-reject algorithm for Beta(1,$\beta$)

Tags: self-study, monte-carlo, rejection-sampling

Consider the pdf

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \beta x^{\beta -1 }\quad 0<x<1 \\ 0\quad \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

for $\beta >1 $

Use the accept-reject algorithm to generate an observation from this pdf.

I have posited that this beta distribution is dominated by a uniform one and thus:

$\beta x^{\beta-1} \leq 1$

The theorem states that if $U\leq \frac{f(x)}{Mg(x)}$, where $U\sim unif(0,1)$ is our simulated uniform RV, we can accept this observation.

In the above $M=1$ and $g(x)=1$. Can I go ahead and set up my inequality like that? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ioannis! Do you think that your question needs to be tagged 'self-study'?

Comment: @Elvis Yes, sorry.

Comment: no problem. I also added 'rejection sampling'.

Comment: Now to your question. You surely don’t have $\beta x^{\beta-1} \le 1$, take e.g $\beta = 2$ and $x=1$... but all you need is $f(x) \le M. g(x)$, i.e if $g(x)$ is the density of $U(0,1)$, $f(x) \le M$.

I’ll try to type a more complete response a bit later.

Comment: $x$ cannot be 1 as it's not in the support. But yes you are otherwise right. The problem is that the function does not have an upper bound and thus there is no supremum.

Comment: Yes for $\beta > 1$ the function does have an upper bound, which is $\beta$. Just compute its derivative $\beta (\beta-1) x^{\beta-2}$, which is non-negative on $(0,1)$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will try to explain how rejection sampling works "in general". If I am clear enough, you should then be able to answer your own question. I won't give proofs but intuitive (or I hope so) "facts".

**Fact 1** If $X$ is drawn in a distribution of density $g(x)$ and $U$ in a uniform $U(0,1)$, then the point $(X, U\times M\times g(X))$ is drawn uniformly in the subgraph of $M g(x)$. Illustration with the normal density and $M = 5$:

```
> x <- rnorm(1e4)
> u <- runif(1e4)
> y <- u*5*dnorm(x)
> plot(x, y, pch=".")
```

[image: plot produced by above R commands]

This fact should be intuitive from the definition of the density: the height $g(x)$ of the subgraph above $x$ is the "probability" to fall in $x$.

**Fact 2** If you can draw uniformly points $(X,Y)$ in the subgraph of $f(x)$ (a density function), then $X$ is distributed with density $f(x)$.

**Fact 3** If $f(x) \le M g(x)$ and you draw points uniformly in the subgraph of $M g(x)$, the points which fall in the subgraph of $f(x)$ are uniformly distributed in it.

Illustration with the tent function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } |x| \ge 1 \\
x+1 & \text{if } -1 < x \le 0 \\ 1-x & \text{if } 0 < x < 1 \end{cases}$

```
 > f <- function(x) ifelse(-1<x & x<=0, x+1, ifelse(0<x & x<1, 1-x, 0))
 > plot(x, y, pch="x", col=ifelse(y < f(x), "black", "red") )
```

[image: cf R code]

All these facts together implies that if you keep only the points $X$ such that $U \times M \times G(X) \le f(X)$, these points are distributed with density $f$.

```
> x1 <- x[ y < f(x) ]
> length(x1)
[1] 2068
> hist(x1)
```

[image: histogram]

Of course this example is only intended for illustration, the proposed algorithm would be a bad way to sample in the tent distribution.

Note that one nice feature of importance sampling, that you can deduce from the above argumentation, is that if you know $f(x)$ only up to some unknown multiplicative constant, you can use the algorithm as well.

Comment: As @Elvis noted in comments to the original post, $\beta$ is an upper bound when $\beta > 1$, which is one of the conditions stated in the OP.  Therefore you can set $M = \beta$.  Note also you don't need an upper bound for $M$, you need an upper bound for the pdf, and $M$ is some number $\geq$ that upper bound.  (Smaller is better because you get a better acceptance ratio, which is directly related to runtime, but you don't HAVE to set $M$ equal to the sup of the pdf.)